# Create chatroom app end up with 'Invalid document reference'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a real time chat application. The following function is creating a new chat room in database.  `getChatRoomId` basically createse a unique id for that chat room which is assigned to `chat_room_id` in database. That `chat_room_id` has a collection which is `chat_room_id` itself and array of `users`. The error occurs when I call this function. I am printing out the data as you see in the method below. The method call is perfect (`here i am`), it looks I have a `chat_room_id` as I expected.Also I have a `chatRoomMap`. However, when I try to printout the information it prints out `null`. Please, check the error section below to see the print out result.

```
createChatRoomAndStartConversation() async{
      if(username != Constants.signedUserName){
        print('here i am');
        String chatRoomId = getChatRoomId(username, Constants.signedUserName);
        List<String> users = [username, Constants.signedUserName];
        Map<String, dynamic> chatRoomMap = {
          'users': users,
          'chat_room_id':chatRoomId
        };
        print('chat room id : $chatRoomId');
      dynamic result=  await _db.createChatRoom(chatRoomId,chatRoomMap);
      print(" result is :" +result.toString());
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>ChatRoom()));
      }else{ print('you cannot send message yourself'); }
    }
```

This is the database method to create a firestore collection

```
  createChatRoom(String chatRoomId, chatRoomMap) {
    Firestore.instance
        .document(chatRoomId)
        .setData(chatRoomMap)
        .catchError((onError) => print(onError.toString()));
  }
```

The error message

```
I/flutter (22917): here i am
I/flutter (22917): chat room id : ahmet_mehmet
I/flutter (22917): chat room map: {users: [ahmet, mehmet], chat_room_id: ahmet_mehmet}
I/flutter (22917): tapped
I/flutter (22917):  result is :null
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but ahmet_mehmet has 1
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.forPath(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:80)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.document(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:249)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.getDocumentReference(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:124)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.onMethodCall(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:877)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(22917):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
I/flutter (22917): PlatformException(error, Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but ahmet_mehmet has 1, null, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but ahmet_mehmet has 1
I/flutter (22917):  at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.forPath(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:80)
I/flutter (22917):  at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.document(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:249)
I/flutter (22917):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.getDocumentReference(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:124)
I/flutter (22917):  at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.onMethodCall(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:877)
I/flutter (22917):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
I/flutter (22917):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
I/flutter (22917):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did similar project a few months ago, this is how i used. maybe will help you

```
@override
  createChatRoom(String chatroomId, chatroomMap) {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("ChatRoom")
        .doc(chatroomId)
        .set(chatroomMap)
        .catchError((e) {
      print(e.toString());
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,@HakkıAkut, you are wonderful, appriciate it. I forget to create the collection of  `chatRooms` :)